# For loops javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Is there a way to set my for loop to hit all instances of `string[i].length == length` before decreasing the value of length by 1? I have messed around with adding while loops but I can't quiet get it.

This script is meant to order an array from greatest to least based on the length of each item. Only problem is I can't figure out how to order it without skipping array item lengths that have already been detected.

```
var string = ["hello", "world", "fishing", "before", "all", "test"];
var length = 0;
word = 0;
for (x = 0; x < string.length; x++) {
if (string[x].length > length) {
   var length = string[x].length;
   word = string[x];
}
}
string1 = [];
for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
if (string[i].length == length) {
  length = string[i].length - 1;
  string1.push(string[i]);
  i = 0;
}
}
console.log(string1);
```

Comment: what is the result you desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
var string = ["hello", "world", "fishing", "before", "all", "test"];

string.sort(function(o1, o2){
    return o1.length - o2.length;
})

console.log(string)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6W4Zf/)

Manual Sorting: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6W4Zf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use javascript's build in `sort` function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

You can pass it a `sortfunction` - use that to compare the string's length and let javascript do the sorting for you.